# How can I improve the performance of this code?

Tags: c#, performance

Can I improve the performance of this code where in I am trying to search a List of Dictionary (tr) from a List of string (_authorizedBks). Is there any better way to code this in C# or supporting languages in .NET?

```
for (int i = tr.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
     if (tr[i].ContainsKey("BK") && !_authorizedBks.Contains(tr[i]["BK"], StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
     {
          removedBks.Add(tr[i]);
     }
}

// where tr is List<Dictionary<string, string>> 
// _authorizedBks is List<string>
// removedBks is List<Dictionary<string, string>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search in those you can give `HashSet<T>` a try? The search in a hashset is amortized at O(1).

```
 HashSet<Dictionary<string, string>> tr = new HashSet<Dictionary<string, string>>();
 HashSet<string> _authorizedBks = new HashSet<string>();
```

Comment: Make sure you construct authorizedBks with a correct IComparer, though.

Comment: this code is a partof web service and there could be C++ or Java clients for this webservice as well, so is Hashtable serializable & consumable by C++ or Java clients?

Comment: @user2736702 Yes, it is.

Comment: @user2736702 You can see at MSDN link here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx , it has a `[Serializable]` attribute

Comment: Another (small) improvement is using TryGet instead of checking for the key and then getting the value by the key.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) class, and then use [.BinarySearch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx)